# unable to open time and system settings in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, system, system-settings

i am unable to **open system setting**s and change time in ubuntu **15.04** on clicking on system settings *nothing happens* same on time 
i have changed the brightness setting registry  earlier as they were not responding to the hot-keys

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Open Terminal from Dash or using ALT+CTRL+T,  run `unity-control-center` .,  then edit your post and add its output.